XGB predict_proba estimates don't match sum of leaves
When using an XGB model in the context of binary classification, I observed that the test estimates given by predict_proba were close but not equal to the results I obtained by summing the outputs of the corresponding leaves for each observation and then converting that sum (which is a log-odds) to probability using the logistic function $\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$. Why does this happen? What am I not taking into account and how can I recreate the results of predict_proba with the individual outputs from the trees?
My code (based on the example given in the XGB docs page) starts by fitting the model:
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data = load_iris()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data['data'][data['target']!=2], 
data['target'][data['target']!=2], test_size=.2, random_state=42)
# create model instance
bst = XGBClassifier(n_estimators=5, max_depth=2, learning_rate=0.5, 
objective='binary:logistic', colsample_bytree=0.3)
# fit model
bst.fit(X_train, y_train)

After doing this I was able to retreive the individual trees of the model and hard-code them into a function to obtain the tree outputs in an array:
def empiric_model(X):
    # t0,...,t4 is for the trees and f0, f1, f2 are the features
    t0 = -0.952112317 if (X['f2']<3).all() else 0.869410515
    t1 = -0.462368667 if (X['f0']<5.5).all() else 0.51116854
    t2 = -0.571811914 if (X['f2']<3).all() else 0.569128871
    t3 = 0.403415382 if (X['f1']<3).all() else 0.0914318636 if ((3<=X['f1'])&(X['f1']<3.0999999)).all() else -0.11495477 if ((3.0999999<=X['f1'])&(X['f1']<3.4000001)).all() else -0.417713255
    t4 = 0.318558067 if (X['f1']<3).all() else 0.0555250905 if ((3<=X['f1'])&(X['f1']<3.20000005)).all() else -0.309806734
    return np.array([t0, t1, t2, t3, t4])

Then I compared both bst.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1] and the sum of the leaves outputs converted into probability. The results of that comparison are shown in the next graph:
# sum of leaf-outputs for each test observation
empirics = np.array([empiric_model(pd.DataFrame(X_test[i:i+1,:], columns=['f0','f1','f2','f3'])).sum() for i in np.arange(X_test.shape[0])])
# convert that into proba using the logistic function
empiric_probas = np.exp(empirics)/(1+np.exp(empirics))
predicted_probas = bst.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
plt.scatter(x=np.arange(empiric_probas.size), y=empiric_probas, c='b', label='empiric')
plt.scatter(x=np.arange(empiric_probas.size), y=predicted_probas, c='r', label='predicted')
plt.xticks(np.arange(empirico_probas.size))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.2))
plt.legend(loc='center right')


I'll explicitly show these values:
empiric_probas is:
array([0.9353348 , 0.9353348 , 0.86878725, 0.13712985, 0.06216319,
   0.08233362, 0.06216319, 0.9353348 , 0.06216319, 0.06216319,
   0.14927792, 0.11448531, 0.9353348 , 0.14927792, 0.9353348 ,
   0.06216319, 0.9353348 , 0.8905786 , 0.13712985, 0.08233362])

while predicted_probas is:
array([0.9411262 , 0.9411262 , 0.8354762 , 0.1493973 , 0.06825472,
   0.06825472, 0.06825472, 0.9411262 , 0.06825472, 0.06825472,
   0.16242756, 0.12502052, 0.9411262 , 0.16242756, 0.9411262 ,
   0.06825472, 0.9411262 , 0.89994967, 0.1493973 , 0.06825472])

Which as you can see are similar but not equal.

what happens if you average the logits instead of the probas?

What do you mean? In which part? because what I did was take the sum of the logits outputted from the trees and then convert that to proba; but I didn't average probas anywhere.

oh word, have you tried averaging the probas then?

If you mean averaging the probas obtained from each leaf (after conversion from logits), that does not work since xgb builds each tree to improve on the previous ones, I did just try it and it does not work. Maybe I should clarify that the two arrays I show at the end of my question are the predicted probabilities (both via predict_proba and empirically) for the test set, so it wouldn't make sense to average those either.

I’m voting to close this question because it is cross-posted to the data science stack exchange with an answer there. In the future, please don't post the same question in multiple places. Instead, choose the community that is the best fit and ask it once, at that site. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/128718/155646
